# How to move multiple objects at the same time in Tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to create a purple rain in Python.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

principal = Tk()
principal.title('Lluvia')
principal.geometry('500x300')
principal.resizable(0, 0)

canvas = Canvas(principal, width = 600, height = 300, bg = 'white')

class gota(object):
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.randrange(0, 500)
        y = random.randrange(-150, -30)
        l = random.randrange(10, 30)
        self.t = l // 10
        self.gota = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + self.t, y + l, outline="", fill = '#8F00FF')
        canvas.pack()
        principal.after(0, self.animacion)

    def animacion(self):
        while(True):
            time.sleep(0.0001)
            canvas.move(self.gota, 0, self.t * 2)
            canvas.update()
            coordenadas = canvas.coords(self.gota)

            if (coordenadas[1] > 310):
                canvas.move(self.gota, 0, -350)
                canvas.update()
```

I can create one drop but the problem is that I want to create multiple drops and all of them need to update at the same time, I tried using threading:

```
threads = []

for i in range(1):
    t = threading.Thread(target = gota)
    t.daemon = True
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

But it doesn't work because I get the error:

RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

It's there a way to do what I'm trying to do in Tkinter? Thanks!

Comment: If all the drops are supposed to move at the same rate, just give them all the same tag name, and use `canvas.move()` on that tag rather than a particular drop.

Comment: Don't call `t.join()` as it will block the tkinter mainloop.  Replace the for loop of `t.join()` by `principal.mainloop()`.